# Unable to find transformer in java to replace values dynamically for existing XSLT file and vice versa

Tags: java, spring-boot, xslt, transform

**Can someone provide me the source code for replacing values dynamically for existing XSLT file using java object**

**XSLT File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CheckDomainCmd"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CheckDomainCmd">
        <epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0 epp-1.0.xsd">
            <command>
                <check>
                    <domain:check xmlns:domain="http://www.nic.cz/xml/epp/domain-1.4" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nic.cz/xml/epp/domain-1.4 domain-1.4.xsd">
                        <domain:name><xsl:value-of select="DomainName"/>.<xsl:value-of select="TLD" /></domain:name>
                    </domain:check>
                </check>
                <clTRID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="RIMTransactionID"/>
                </clTRID>
            </command>
        </epp>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Java Object:**

```
public class checkDomain {

    private String DomainName;
    private String TLD;
    private String RIMTransactionID;
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

I need a source code in java/spring to put values to the XSLT select attribute dynamically.
For Example, in java object we have the following values, how to transform java object values to XSLT attributes:

```
public class XSLTConversion {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CheckDomain checkDomain = new CheckDomain():
        checkDomain.setDomainName("test");
        checkDomain.setTLD("com");
        checkDomain.setRIMTransactionID("qwertyco123456");
        
        replaceValuesToXSLTFile(checkDomain, "checkdomain.xslt");
    }
    public static void replaceValuesToXSLTFile(CheckDomain checkDomain, String fileName) {
        
    }
}
```

After transformation, I need the file content like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CheckDomainCmd"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CheckDomainCmd">
        <epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0 epp-1.0.xsd">
            <command>
                <check>
                    <domain:check xmlns:domain="http://www.nic.cz/xml/epp/domain-1.4" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nic.cz/xml/epp/domain-1.4 domain-1.4.xsd">
                        <domain:name><xsl:value-of select="test"/>.<xsl:value-of select="com" /></domain:name>
                    </domain:check>
                </check>
                <clTRID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="qwertyco123456"/>
                </clTRID>
            </command>
        </epp>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have read this and I have no idea what you want to achieve.

Comment: Perhaps you want to lookup how to use <xsl:if test="" />, which allows you to control what is output in certain conditions. similarly <xsl:choose><xsl:when /></xsl:choose> i how you set up a switch/case statement.

Comment: Bryn - I need source code in java/spring to transform XSLT attributes with java object values as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Your XSLT code needs to declare global parameters and reference them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="DomainName"/>
    <xsl:param name="TLD"/>
    <xsl:param name="RIMTransactionID"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CheckDomainCmd"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CheckDomainCmd">
        <epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0 epp-1.0.xsd">
            <command>
                <check>
                    <domain:check xmlns:domain="http://www.nic.cz/xml/epp/domain-1.4" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nic.cz/xml/epp/domain-1.4 domain-1.4.xsd">
                        <domain:name><xsl:value-of select="$DomainName"/>.<xsl:value-of select="$TLD" /></domain:name>
                    </domain:check>
                </check>
                <clTRID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$RIMTransactionID"/>
                </clTRID>
            </command>
        </epp>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then your Java code can create a `Transformer` from the XSLT and use e.g. `transformer.setParameter("TLD", checkDomain.getTLD())` (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setParameter-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) and so on for the other parameters before calling the `transform` method.